# Prove that $\frac{2022}{n} + 4n$ is a perfect square iff $\frac{2022}{n} - 8n$ is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

> Prove that $\frac{2022}{n} + 4n$ is a perfect square iff $\frac{2022}{n} - 8n$ is a perfect square

My solution was to substitute all the positive divisors of $2022$ into the $2$ expressions and observe that they are perfect squares iff $n=6$ which confirms the above relation. However, I don't think the problem setters were looking for this *indirect* proof, so I wonder if there is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I would call that a proof by exhaustion, which I consider to be a direct type of proof, not an indirect proof.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I called it _indirect_ because the relationship was being established by connecting both expressions to a _third_ result and not linking them directly.

Comment: What did the "problem setters" say which makes you think that they were looking for a different proof? Unless specified otherwise, in my mind all proofs are divided into *correct* proofs and *incorrect* proofs. I have not checked the numbers but I presume you've exhausted all possibilities and thus this proof is *correct*.

Comment: @Random what is this "third result" you speak of?

Comment: @AdamRubinson The _third_ result is a property that both expressions have i.e. they are perfect square iff $n=6$. My assumption was that a _direct_ proof would involve manipulating the first expression into the second expression that demonstrates that the first expression is a perfect square iff the second expression is a perfect square i.e. not having to rely on an external property of both expressions.

Comment: Yeah, but I doubt there will be a direct proof that doesn't inspect the prime factors of $2022,$ although I would love to be wrong about this.

Comment: Good **meta-cheating**, where you are trying to infiltrate the mind of the problem composer, to determine what their intended solution is.  And, good thinking that there is no real educational value in a brute force solution.  Personally, I don't see any signficance in the expression $~\displaystyle \frac{2022}{n}$ that would indicate under what circumstances that two squares in such a neighborhood would be separated by a difference of $(12n)$.  So, I surmise that this is simply a poor problem to pose, and that the problem composer is in the wrong line of work.

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can greatly reduce the number of cases to check by working modulo $4$. We have $$2022 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 337 \equiv 2\cdot 3\cdot 1 \pmod 4.$$ Since a square must be $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, we can immediately reduce to the two cases $n\in\{6, 2022\}$. And of course $n=2022$ is impossible since $\frac{2022}{n}-8n$ will be negative.

EDIT: I made an oversight, see the comments. To show that $1+4\cdot2022$ isn't square, we can use that
$$
1+4\cdot2022 = x^2
\iff 2022 = \frac{x-1}{2}\cdot\frac{x+1}{2}=m(m+1).
$$
We can check manually that $2022$ doesn't factorize in this way. To wit, the largest consecutive factors are $2$ and $3$, whose product is less than $2022$.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that a square must be $0$ or $1 \bmod{4}$. That seems like an interesting problem to prove.

Comment: @Random Oh, that's a very useful fact, proven by just checking the four cases of $n^2$ mod $4$. In general, squares can only be around half of all values modulo any given integer (is the very short version of the story). You can look up *quadratic residues* if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Comment: Note my method of checking. We do not need to find any square roots, just look at the factor list. (We could even count the number of greater versus lesser factors, the consecutive factors would give the right product iff these counts are equal.)

Comment: @OscarLanzi I agree, that's the also the most direct method I had in mind.

Comment: @Random Yeah, I learnt recently about it too in Axler's History of Mathematics which is a cool read